# Best way to enter(insert) the content in drupal, so a non techie can edit the content

Tags: nodes

I am some what new to drupal tho familiar with CMS tho drupal way is to put into views tho i dont see how best a non techie can edit such content what am i missing  thank you

Comment: please clearly describe what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a WYSIWYG editor installed for your end-users?

You can use CKEditor, or a number of other editors, and install as a module. Here is a walkthrough for installing CKEditor: [CKEditor Quick Start](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Open_Source/Drupal_7/Quick_Start), 
 Or you can install the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module and choose from a handful of WYSIWYG editors to use on your site. By doing so, you would give your content editors a way to create content similarly to how we enter our answers and code examples here on StackExchange and your users will not need to know any html or code to get the job done.